# Как сделать разрезание Mesh на подобие Paper.io 2

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать разрезание Mesh, чтобы этот розовый куб(на скриншоте) прорезал эту синию плиту при движении(двигаю с помощью Rigidbody), при этом записывая прорезанную площадь в переменную.

Вот как примерно выглядит это в игре Paper.io 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: На скриншоте с Mesh ничего не делают, это слишком сложно и ресурсоёмко. Это сделано шейдером.

Comment: @Yaroslaw, А как сделать шейдером?

Comment: Ok Google: unity3d hole shader